# Реализация входа в систему на Django

Tags: python, django

Я создаю вход пользователей в систему на Django. Ниже код метода, который получает из формы login и pswd (пароль). Однако, когда я использую метод request.user, он выводит ошибку:
TypeError at /logging
'str' object is not callable.

Как эту ошибку исправить? Код метода:

```
def logging_in(request):
    login = request.POST.get("login")
    pswd = request.POST.get("pswd")
    if User.objects.filter(username=login).exists():
        user = User.objects.get(username=login)
        if user.check_password(pswd):
            user = authenticate(request, username=login, password=pswd)
            login(request, user, backend = None)
```

Comment: Никакой код после return не выполняется, а значит функция login не вызвалась и вход не выполнился

Comment: Ну а теперь оказалось, что login это не функция, а строка, которую вы задали вот тут `login = request.POST.get("login")` — а строки нельзя вызывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пишу здесь, т.к. не могу оставлять комментарии.

Ошибка выдается потому, что вы именуете переменную login в первой строке и затем используете ее же как имя пользователя в функции authenticate()(или что-то похожее на это, мне не понятно просто).